# remove message.author reaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I wanted to remove the user's reaction when he reacts, leaving only one, the bot's own

I've already seen some tutorials on this, but I haven't found this method

```
const test = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("random")
    .setTitle("help")
    .setDescription(`**this a test**`)

message.channel.send(test).then(msg => {
    msg.react('').then(r => {
      msg.react('').then(r => {
          })
          })

const hiFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;
const hi2Filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;

const edit = msg.createReactionCollector(hiFilter);
const edit2 = msg.createReactionCollector(hi2Filter);

edit.on('collect', r2 => {
      
      test.setTitle("test edited")
      test.setDescription("edited")

msg.edit(test)

})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This code removes the reaction if the ID of the user that added the reaction is not your bot's ID. Replace `<Client>` with whatever you've declared your Discord client as.

```
edit.on('collect', (r2, user) => {
    if (user.id !== <Client>.user.id) r2.remove().catch(console.log);

    test.setTitle("test edited");
    test.setDescription("edited");

    msg.edit(test);
});
```

Comment: its work, but it also removes the bot's, I want it to remove only the user's, still keeping the bot's reaction

Comment: It shouldn't do. Are you sure you're providing the if statement with the correct bot ID? It would be useful to see exactly how you've added it to your program.